# Getting MultiValueDictKeyError on Django while trying to receiving a stripe hook

Tags: python-3.x, django, stripe-payments, stripes, zebra-striping

I am getting a `django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError` while trying to receive a stripe signal when a subscription's charge fails,

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aditya/dev/cn/pmx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/aditya/dev/cn/pmx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/aditya/dev/cn/pmx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/aditya/dev/cn/pmx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/views.py", line 67, in sentry_wrapped_callback
    return callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/aditya/dev/cn/pmx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aditya/dev/cn/pmx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zebra/views.py", line 38, in webhooks
    request_data = json.loads(request.POST["request_data"])
  File "/home/aditya/dev/cn/pmx_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 80, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'request_data'
[13/Nov/2021 09:36:29] "POST /zebra/webhooks/ HTTP/1.1" 500 121292
```

I am using

- django 2.2
- Python 3.7.12

Thanks in advance for any solutions and suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need for `json.loads`, you can just use the `request.POST.get()` method like this

`request_data = request.POST.get("request_data")`

This will return a `None` value if there is no `request_data` key in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @dichter, for your response. the line `request_data = json.loads(request.POST["request_data"])` is from django's core module `zebra`. `.../env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zebra/views.py", line 38, in webhooks`